# Binary search on vector objects of an element greater than an attribute

Tags: c++

I have a vector which contains lot of elements of my class X . 
I need to find the first occurrence of an element in this vector say S such that S.attrribute1 > someVariable. someVariable will not be fixed    . How can I do binary_search for this ? (NOT c++11/c++14) . I can write std::binary_search with search function of greater  (which ideally means check of equality) but that would be wrong ? Whats the right strategy for fast searching ?

Comment: Use [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) with a custom comparison functor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `std::binary_search` to succeed, the range need to be sorted.`std::binary_search`, `std::lower_bound` works on sorted containers. So every time you add a new element into your `vector` you need to keep it sorted.

For this purpose you can use `std::lower_bound` in your insertion:

```
class X;
class XCompare
{
public:
    bool operator()(const X& first, const X& second) const
    {
        // your sorting logic
    }
};

X value(...);
auto where = std::lower_bound(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector), value, XCompare());
vector.insert(where, value);
```

And again you can use `std::lower_bound` to search in your vector:

```
auto where = std::lower_bound(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector), searching_value, XCompare());
```

Don't forget to check if `std::lower_bound` was successful:

```
bool successed = where != std::end(vector) && !(XCompare()(value, *where));
```

Or directly use `std::binary_search` if you only want to know that element is in vector.

Answer (score 3):

A binary search can only be done if the vector is in sorted order ***according to the binary search's predicate***, by definition.

So, unless all elements in your vector for which "*S.attribute1 > someVariable*" are located after all elements that are not, this is going to be a non-starter, right out of the gate.

If all elements in your vector are sorted in some other way, that "some other way" is the only binary search that can be implemented.

Assuming that they are, you must be using a comparator, of some sort, that specifies strict weak ordering on the attribute, in order to come up with your sorted vector in the first place:

```
class comparator {

public:
    bool operator()(const your_class &a, const your_class &b) const
    {
          return a.attribute1 < b.attribute1;
    }
};
```

The trick is that if you want to search using the attribute value alone, you need to use a comparator that can be used with `std::binary_search` which is [defined as follows](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

> ```
> template< class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare >
> bool binary_search( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last,
>                     const T& value, Compare comp );
> ```
>
> For std::binary_search to succeed, the range [first, last) must be
>   at least partially ordered, i.e. it must satisfy all of the following
>   requirements:
>
> for all elements, if element < value or comp(element, value) is true
>   then !(value < element) or !comp(value, element) is also true

So, the only requirement is that `comp(value, element)` and `comp(element, value)` needs to work. You can pass the attribute value for `T`, rather than the entire element in the vector to search for, as long as your comparator can deal with it:

```
class search_comparator {

public:
    bool operator()(const your_class &a, const attribute_type &b) const
    {
          return a.attribute1 < b;
    }

    bool operator()(const attribute_type &a, const your_class &b) const
    {
          return a < b.attribute1;
    }
};
```

Now, you should be able to use `search_comparator` instead of `comparator`, and do a binary search by the attribute value.

And, all bets are off, as I said, if the vector is not sorted by the given attribute. In that case, you'll need to use `std::sort` it explicitly, first, or come up with some custom container that keeps track of the vector elements, in the right order, separately and in addition to the main vector that holds them. Using pointers, perhaps, in which case you should be able to execute a binary search on the pointers themselves, using a similar search comparator, that looks at the pointers, instead.